# How to display two similars fields with possibly identical content?

Tags: forms, input-fields

I currently work on a subcontracting tool in which I have to register a direct client (billing) and a final client (work) with the address of the final client (work place).

The direct client is just here in case we don't work directly with the final client (it's only a remimder).

[image: App wireframe]

What is the best way to display this fields in my form?

I've already thought to:

1. Ask the user to enter the client twice if the direct and final client are the same
2. Leave the direct client field empty if the direct and final client are the same

But I have no idea how to do this to be clear for the user.

**EDIT:**
After reading the "possible duplicate", the way suggest to solve my problem is to add a "Set a different direct client" checkbox to toggle the "direct client" field display. But I have only one field ("direct client") to work with, so I am not sure that a checkbox is appropriate to toggle only **one** field.

Comment: I've juste read the "possible duplicate" and if I undestand, the best way to solve by problem is to add a "Set a different direct client" checkbox to toggle the "direct client" field display.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could just start filling the final client text box with the same text as the user is typing in the direct client with a grayish color and then user could also type in the final client!

Comment: It seems intersting. Is there a special reason to apply a grayish color on the second field ? I'm afraid the user will tought the second field is disabled.

Comment: Yeah there is difference between the textbox being grayish and the textcolor being grayish!! grayish color is open used as secondary to the black in the sense it is dependent. When the user will start typing it will see the final client with the same text dynamically. When the user will click the final client textbox you can just remove all the text and if user does not type and click somewhere else you can repopulate the that textbox with the same text from the direct client